# Error: resource youtube#videoListResponse not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-data-api, discord.js

if youtube playlist includes a private video, the bot will get an error.

Error: resource youtube#videoListResponse not found

Here is my code.

```
if (url.match(/^https?:\/\/(www.youtube.com|youtube.com)\/playlist(.*)$/)) {
    const playlist = await youtube.getPlaylist(url);
    const videos = await playlist.getVideos();
    for (const video of Object.values(videos)) {
        const video2 = await youtube.getVideoByID(video.id);
        await handleVideo(video2, message, voiceChannel, true);
    }
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    embed
        .setDescription("✅ Added playlist: " + `**${playlist.title}**`)
        .setColor(0xcc0000)
        .setTitle('Bot')
        .setTimestamp()
    message.channel.send(embed).then(function(message) {
        message.delete(5000);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        throw err;
    });
    return;
}
```

Comment: You can't view a private video, it's private...

Answer (score 0):

Hello I just went through this same problem and went to search on any topic I found how to solve it but reading some codes and doing a manual "debug" to find exactly where is giving this error I found a way to solve it Below is an example :

Old code:

```js
    if(url.match(/^https?:\/\/(www.youtube.com|youtube.com)\/playlist(.*)$/)){
                const playlist = await youtube.getPlaylist(url)
                const videos = await playlist.getVideos()
                for(const video of Object.values(videos)){
                    const video2 = await youtube.getVideoByID(video.id)
                    await handleVideo(video2, message, voiceChannel, true)
                }
            }
```

New code:

```js
//Note: as a freebie, there are some error prevention that may occur in the future.

    if(url.match(/^https?:\/\/(www.youtube.com|youtube.com)\/playlist(.*)$/)){
                const playlist = await youtube.getPlaylist(url).catch(erro => {
                    return message.reply("A Playlist é privada ou não existe!")
                });
                const videos = await playlist.getVideos().catch(erro => { 
                    message.reply("Ocorreu um problema ao colocar um dos vídeos da playlist na fila!'")
                });
                for(const video of Object.values(videos)){
                    try{
                    const video2 = await youtube.getVideoByID(video.id)
                    await handleVideo(video2, message, voiceChannel, true)
                } catch {
                }
                }
                message.reply(`A playlist **${playlist.title}** foi adicionada a lista de músicas!`)
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to update this question and I already found out how to solve it.
I solve it with adding a filter to check the video is private or not.
https://hastebin.com/pitifudihe.js